# Flask-Login is_authenticated inconsistency

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using a test unit to verify logins with Flask-Login. The purpose of this is to verify the behavior of a user whose credentials are incorrect:

```
    def test_login_user(self):
        '''test user login'''
        user = User(email='teste@teste.com', pass='teste')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        response = self.app.post('/login_user', data={'email':
             'teste@teste.com', 'pass': 'tste'}, follow_redirects=True)

        print(response.get_data(), user.is_authenticated)
        assert user.is_authenticated == True
        self.assertEqual(response.status, "200 OK")
```

The problem is that `assert user.is_authenticated` pass the test, even though the last assert fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 58, in test_login_user
self.assertEqual(response.status, "200 OK")
AssertionError: '401 UNAUTHORIZED' != '200 OK'
- 401 UNAUTHORIZED
+ 200 OK
```

My implementation of login view is the following:

```
@app.route('/login_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_user():
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_requested = User.query.filter_by(email=request.form['email']).first()
    if user_requested is not None:
        if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['pass'], user_requested.pass):
            return redirect(url_for('student'))
    return redirect(url_for('error'))
```

Also, on class User, I'm extending UserMixin. Why doesn't user.is_authenticated returns False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `login_user` in the login view.  When you redirect, `login_required` fails on the protected view.  Pass the user you fetched from the database to `login_user` before redirecting.

All users instances are authenticated, even if they are not logged in.  Only the anonymous user is not authenticated.  Look at `current_user` inside a context to see which user is logged in.  You can keep the context around by using a `with app.test_client() as c` block.

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    r = c.post('/login', data={...})
    self.assertEqual(current_user.email, '...')
```

Here's a minimal example of a Flask-Login setup and test.

```
import unittest
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from flask.ext.login import login_required
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, current_user

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.testing = True

    def tearDown(self):
        app.testing = False

    def test_login(self):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            r = c.post('/login', data={'id': 400617}, follow_redirects=True)
            # current_user is only set in context
            self.assertEqual(current_user.id, 400617)

        # resopnse doesn't depend on context, so can be tested outside block
        self.assertEqual(r.status, '200 OK')
        # any non-anonymous user is authenticated, even if not logged in
        self.assertTrue(User(123).is_authenticated)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Stack Overflow'
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

@login.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    return User(int(id))

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return 'index'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User(id=request.form.get('id', type=int))
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return 'login'
```

```
$ python -m unittest -v app
test_login (app.TestApp) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

OK
```